# What's the idea behind useState functionality in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming

I am learning ReactJS and I understand the benefits of functional programming. However, I am a little concerned about the actual useState approach. If we assume a variable to be changed, then why declaring it const in the first place?

I see that I can simply use `let number = 4;` and then render it like this `<p>{number}</p>`. What I cannot do however is to re-render it automatically just by changing it, for example using onClick event like this `<p onClick={() => ++number }></p>`. Why is it that so? Is there a specific reason I am missing why it was implemented the way it is? I mean why the developers have decided that if the value needs to be re-rendered upon change, then it must be a const value declared with the help of useState functionality?

I am asking this because I am suspecting I am missing some good points behind this and I would like to understand them.

Comment: Because if you just increment a local variable, how does React know that the virtual DOM should be updated and then changes applied to the real page? I'd recommend watching e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdNJ3fydeao to get a better idea about what's happening.

Comment: *What I cannot do however is to re-render it automatically just by changing it* Because reassignment alone cannot have side-effects in JS (in almost all cases). If a particular functionality isn't possible in JS, it's not possible in React/JSX either, without new operators/syntax.

Comment: OP, are you writing class components or function components? Without `useState`, function components that must have state with flat out not work because the component will regenerate its state every time it's rerendered. `useState` in function components doesn't create an internal state but rather an internal reference to an external state. It's like an `IORef` in other functional languages. IIRC it enables a "global" state while also ensuring atomicity. It's a bit like using redux without using redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is declared as a const because you are not allowed to set it directly. In React the state itself is immutable. You are just allowed to change it over setState (or setNumber in your case) or with actions if you use redux.

But why is that? It may seem unnecessary cumbersome in the beginning

First of all, if your variable number changes, react has to trigger a rerender.
If the state is mutable, it requires data-binding because if the number is set, it has to update the view.

In javascript, data-binding works for simple objects, but not well for arrays. Vue.js for example, as an alternative that uses two-way data binding, had a lot of trouble in its early versions when dealing with arrays. That's why there are now only seven predefined methods to interact with arrays (which they added later to solve that problem). [Vue Js Array Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods)

So a simple reason to declare the state as const is that it works better with arrays. And if you watch the example you gave, `setNumber(number + 1)` is not that much more to write than `number++`. But `setState(newArray)` works, and `newArray[i] = newElement` would not work, because due to javascript limitations this cannot trigger a rerender.

Secondly, it is a nicer design concept. Think of your component as a function, that returns a view to a state. And if the state changes, you get a new view. It simplifies relationships between properties in your component. If you were allowed to change your state while rendering your component, it would create a mess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understood correctly, the idea behind this (at least one of (if there are multiple)) is to encapsulate re-rendering technique. In C# I used to implement an interface called INotifyPropertyChanged when the class field was changed. Subscribing to that event would allow view to be redrawn. However in WPF this is also done automatically with data binding. So in ReactJS that state thing is an alternative to the data binding if I understood it correctly

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're thinking of a functional component as if it was stateful. But it isn't. It's a function and once you run it, that's it.

Take this example:

```js
function useState() {
  let value = 1

  function setValue(v) {
    value = v
  }

  return [value, setValue]
}

function myFunction () {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();  // <----- we use const here

  return null
}
```

Even though we're using const, the `value` variable only exists within the function, once the function returns that's it. It's the same for components.

The actual value of `value` is stored in a whole different scope, where `useEffect` has access to.

Here's a [deep dive](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/) on how react works internally if you're interested

Comment: So is the whole component re-rendered when some value inside it changes? I understood it as it does. Asking just to double-check.

Answer (score 1):

React works in render cycles, i.e. some state is declared, the DOM (UI) is computed during the "render phase", and then flushed to the actual DOM during the "commit phase".

Within each cycle state is considered constant (`const` in JS simply means a variable can't be assigned a new value, you could just as easily declare it with `let` or `var` instead and react would work the same) but for react's purpose, state is constant *during* a render cycle. When it is updated via one of the state update methods, react then kicks off another render cycle (update state, compute diff, commit to DOM) and re-renders when necessary.

This process is important and the reason why external state mutations are considered anti-pattern, it goes against the react workflow and leads to buggy code or worse, UI that doesn't update as expected.

React [component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

[image]

> I cannot do however is to re-render it automatically just by changing
> it, for example using onClick event like this `<p onClick={() => ++number }></p>`. Why is it that so?

React state updates use a process called [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) to figure out what changed and what to re-render. In really simplistic terms, when react state is updated it is updated with a new object reference so a shallow object comparison can more quickly detect that the component state updated.

Declaring state and doing `++number` simply changes the value but not the reference, and would be considered a state mutation, an anti-pattern in react.